# Partitioning time series

Tags: time-series, gathering

I have a time series dataset I'm trying to plot by Year:

```
{{DateObject[{1991, 7}], 3.52659}, {DateObject[{1991, 8}], 
  3.18089}, {DateObject[{1991, 9}], 3.25222}, {DateObject[{1991, 10}],
   3.611}, {DateObject[{1991, 11}], 3.56587}, {DateObject[{1991, 12}],
   4.30637}, {DateObject[{1992, 1}], 5.08834}, {DateObject[{1992, 2}],
   2.81452}, {DateObject[{1992, 3}], 2.98581}, {DateObject[{1992, 4}],
   3.20478}}
...
```

I plotted it this way `DateListPlot[data]`:

[image: Time Series]

Now I'm trying to plot it by Year, following the example from here: http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/semantic-data-import/analyze-retail-sales-data.html

But instead of grouping by `City`, I'm grouping by `Year`:

```
dataByYear = 
  GroupBy[data, (DateValue[#[[1]], 
       "Year"]) & -> ({DateValue[#[[1]], "MonthName"], #[[2]]} &)];
```

But when I try to plot it I get the following error message:

```
DateListPlot[dataByYear[[All]], PlotLegends -> Keys[dataByYear]]
```

> ```
> <|1991->{{July ,3.526591`},{August ,3.180891`},{September
> ,3.252221`},{October ,3.611003`},{November ,3.565869`},{December
> ,4.306371`}},<<16>>,2008->{{January ,29.665356`},{February
> ,21.654285`},{March ,18.264945`},{April ,23.107677`},{May
> ,22.91251`},{June ,19.43174`}}|>
> is not a valid dataset or list of datasets. >>
> ```

I checked the dataset returned by the `GroupBy` from Wolfram's example, and they do look very similar. The only difference seems to be the `Keys` are the name of the cities and in my case the `Keys` are the `Years`.

What's wrong with my code?

Edit:

I abandoned the previous approach and decide to try plotting every year separately and them "joining" them (Sorry, I don't know the proper Mathematica term for this). This is how far I've managed to go:

```
Show[Table[DateListPlot[dataByYear[i]], {i, 1992, 2000}], PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

[image: Second shot]

Now how do I label and color each year in order to look something like the image below?

[image: Colored]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: DateListPlot expects the abscissa to be a full date or Absolutetime, not just an integer or a string month name.  Instead of using DateValue try DateList and also separate the values from the Keys using Norm or Part.

Comment: I don't think that's it. The abscissa is not a string nor integer. It's a DateObject. And if I plot the same data with only one year with `DateListPlot[dateByGroup[1992]]` it works fine. It's the same data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With version 10

```
data = WeatherData["KATL", "Temperature", {{2004, 1}, {2014, 10}, "Month"}]
ds = TimeSeriesWindow[data, {{#, 1}, {#, 12}}] & /@ Range[2004, 2014];
ListPlot[ds[[#]]["Values"] & /@ Range@Length@ds, Joined -> True, 
Ticks -> {Transpose[{Range[12], {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", 
"Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"}}], Automatic}]
```

[image: SAmple]

Comment: (+1) I cannot call this solution straightforward but it works. Obviously the `TimeSeries` functionality still needs polishing.

Comment: Mathematica was complaining (showing error messages) about my data when I tried to put it into a TimeSeries, but then I realized it was just a frontend problem. I followed through even with the error messages and indeed it worked! Thank you very, very much sir!

Answer (score 4):

Just to add some more options and expose some other time series functionality.

```
TimeSeriesSplit[ts_, dt_, align_: None] := Block[{f, tsa, dates},
  tsa = Sequence @@@ (TimeSeriesAggregate[ts, dt, f]["Values"]);
  dates = Internal`PartitionRagged[ts["Dates"], Length /@ tsa];
  If[align =!= None,
   TemporalData[tsa, {dates[[1, 1]], Automatic, align}]
   ,
   TemporalData[tsa, Partition[dates, 1]]
   ]
  ]
```

Lets try it out with some weather data.

```
data = WeatherData["KATL","Temperature", {{2004, 1}, {2014, 10}, "Month"}];
```

Without setting the last argument it just chunks the data.

```
DateListPlot@TimeSeriesSplit[data, "Year"]
```

[image]

Or if you set the optional align option...

```
DateListPlot@TimeSeriesSplit[data, "Year", "Month"]
```

[image]

Probably not very robust but it might serve as a nice starting point for someone.

Comment: This is very helpful. I'll try it out too. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference, I will post the code I used for the final solution. It wouldn't have been possible without PatoCriollo's help:

```
tdata = TemporalData[data[[All, 2]], {Map[DateString, data[[All, 1]]]}];
ds = TimeSeriesWindow[tdata, {{#, 1}, {#, 12}}] & /@ Range[1991, 2008];

ListPlot[ds[[#]]["Values"] & /@ Range@Length@ds, Joined -> True, 
 Ticks -> {Transpose[{Range[12], {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", 
      "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"}}], Automatic}, 
 PlotLegends -> Range[1991, 2008]]
```

Note that if I execute the first 2 lines without `;` (semicolon) at the end, Mathematica will print nasty error messages.

I later realized that the problem was only at the frontend, when it tried to show me the results. My data is only at the "month" granularity level (no days, only month and year: `"Jan 1994"`), and that's causing problems with the Mathematica's frontend.

So I continued and executed the last line and sure enough Mathematica plot my data correctly, even with the previous error messages.

If you leave the `;` after the first two lines, it won't try to show the result of those expressions and won't complain.

Here's the final plot:

[image: Final plot thanks to PatoCriollo]