# RandomFunction and Histograms

Tags: programming, probability-or-statistics, time-series

```
RandomFunction[QueueingProcess[3, 5], {0, 15}]
Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"]
```

gives a very nice way to see the histogram based on the specified process. However, my process data comes from the observed values.

I tried to assign

```
data={{0.0, 0}, {2.0199, 1}, {3.3544, 0}, {6.2484, 1}, {7.0204, 
  0}, {16.6974, 1}, {17.4653, 0}, {33.1508, 1}, {33.5897, 
  2}, {36.3656, 1}, {48.2725, 2}, {57.1227, 1}, {67.6013, 
  0}, {69.2908, 1}, {72.8626, 0}, {86.6029, 1}, {87.6669, 
  0}, {120.7927, 1}, {122.8568, 0}, {125.4026, 1}, {131.7756, 
  0}, {132.8221, 1}, {135.0257, 0}, {140.9808, 1}, {147.2401, 
  0}, {160.6539, 1}, {162.4473, 0}, {170.9659, 1}, {177.8401, 
  2}, {181.3527, 1}, {195.5088, 0}, {205.4589, 1}, {211.7528, 2}}
```

Where the first item corresponds to the time and the second to the actual value. However, mathematica does not seem to recognize it, taking the first item as the value.

This is a continuous process and I only have records when the value changes, i.e. from 0 to 1, to 2 to 1, etc.

How can I create a Histogram based on such time data?

Comment: please note that you can also Upvote (click the up triangle) an answer -- especially when you Accept it:)

Comment: I know, but it requires registration. I'll try it. Thank you for pointing out!

Comment: Tangentially related: "[Partitioning time series](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64501/280)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For instance, if I have a process and it first spends 2 minutes in
>   state 1, then 200 minutes in state 2 and 10 minutes in state 0:
>   {{0,0},{2,1}, {202, 2}, {212,0}} I would want the time be included in
>   the calculation of the relative frequency as opposed to the number of
>   occurences.

Based on this [description](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64659/randomfunction-and-histograms/64664#comment181347_64660), I can suggest the following approach:

```
data = {{0, 0}, {2, 1}, {202, 2}, {212, 0}, {213, 0}, {214, 1}, {230, 
    2}, {252, 0}};

cd = {Total@#[[;; , 1]], #[[1, 2]]} & /@ 
   GatherBy[Transpose[{Differences[data[[;; , 1]]], data[[2 ;;, 2]]}],
     Last];
```

Plotting total times in minutes:

```
BarChart[{cd[[;; , 1]]}, ChartLegends -> cd[[;; , 2]], AxesLabel -> "min"]
```

> [image: hist]

Plotting relative frequencies of states:

```
BarChart[{cd[[;; , 1]]/Total[cd[[;; , 1]]]}, 
 ChartLegends -> cd[[;; , 2]], AxesLabel -> "probability"]
```

> [image: hist2]

Computing mean from the relative frequencies:

```
mean = cd[[;; , 2]].cd[[;; , 1]]/Total[cd[[;; , 1]]]
```

> ```
> 145/84
> ```

---

And an approach using `WeightedData` with weights being the time counts:

```
wd = WeightedData @@ Reverse[Transpose[cd]];

BarChart[{wd["EmpiricalPDF"][[2]]}, 
 ChartLegends -> wd["EmpiricalPDF"][[1]], AxesLabel -> "probability"]
Mean[wd]
Variance[wd]
```

> [image: bc]
>
> ```
> 145/84
>
> 3251/1750
> ```

Comment: Alexey, thank you for your reply. I really appreciate it. It seems like I need to adjust this to account for many different values (beyond 0,1,2). Would you please let me know how to allow for more values?

Comment: The described approach is very general and does not depend on the number of values and/or their types, in accordance with the spirit of *Mathematica* the language. You can use arbitrary number of states and describe them not necessarily as `Integer`s: `Strings` will work the same way, no changes in the code are needed.

Comment: Alexey, is it possible to convert the value (i.e. the y axis) to reflect probability (i.e. relative frequency)?

Comment: Also, Is it possible to find out the mean, the variance of this data?THANK YOU SO MUCH! I spent about 20-30 hours before posting here, so your help is huge!

Comment: I updated the answer with the code for plotting relative frequencies. As to the *mean* and *variance*, it is not completely clear to me how should we understand them in this context. It seems that some model of the underlying random process is needed in order to produce the definitions of these quantities. If you have such definitions, please include them in the question.

Comment: I added `WeightedData`-based approach. I am not sure however what assumptions this approach implies.

Answer (score 3):

`RandomFunction` produces a `TemporalData` object.  The action of `Histogram` on `TemporalData` is to just do a histogram of the values (ignoring time stamps).

```
td = RandomFunction[QueueingProcess[3, 5], {0, 15}];
GraphicsRow[{Histogram[td], Histogram[td["Values"]]}]
```

[image]

Thus, you can either wrap your data in `TemporalData` or just make a histogram of the values without the time stamps.

```
GraphicsRow[{Histogram[TemporalData@data], Histogram[data[[All, 2]]]}]
```

[image]

**EDIT**

To accomplish more what I think you are after you can weight the observations by the amount of time spent at each state. This will ignore the last state because we don't know how long you stopped there.

```
Histogram[WeightedData[data[[1 ;; -2, 2]], Differences@data[[All, 1]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Andy, Thank you very much for your help. Do I understand it correctly that both approaches won't give true histogram? For instance, if I have a process and it first spends 2 minutes in state 1, then 200 minutes in state 2 and 10 minutes in state 0: {{0,0},{2,1}, {202, 2}, {212,0}} I would want the time be included in the calculation of the relative frequency as opposed to the number of occurences.

Comment: You do understand that correctly.